# JTextField действие при клике

Tags: java, swing

У меня есть массив `JTextField[][]`, после ввода символа в `JTextField[i][j]`, остальные поля блокируются(`jTextField_enter.setEditable(false);`). 
Дальше мне нужно кликом мышкой выбирать несколько JTextField, пробовал `jTextField_enter.addActionListener();` - не реагирует на клики. Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реакция на клики добавляется так, как и на любой другой `JComponent`

```
java.awt.Component#addMouseListener
java.awt.Component#addMotionMouseListener
```

Попробуйте этот пример:

```
    JComponent c = new JTextField();
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 22));
    c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseClicked");
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mousePressed");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseReleased");
        }
    });

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(new Dimension(200,100));
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(c);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
```